# How do you apply JS all countries in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my country selection box have all the countries with javascript

This is the form now in HTML:

```
<form action="action_page.php">

    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
      <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

As you can see i have my option values set to 3 different alternatives but would instead like to know how to make a "all countries" selection list instead

i am very new to learning JS so would like if someone just writes exactly how to do it.

thankyou in advance

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're stuck on. Just Google a "list of all countries", then put them one by one in an `<option>`.

Comment: You can select only a single option from `select` element. If you need multiple selections, add `multiple` attirbute to the select element.

Comment: Many different suggestions when the question is not clear. Maybe OP wants a dynamic solution for filling the select with all country options via javascript, lol, don't know for sure.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You currently have "Sweden", "Spain", and "USA" — are you saying that you want a choice "All" that means all three of those countries, or are you saying you want the selection list to include all of the (195) countries in the world?

Answer (score 0):

1. You would add another option with value 'all'.  Your handler would then check for the all value, and then replace it with your items.
2. You would add all items to another option, with the value as a string list, using a delimiter such as a comma. Your handler would split this string value into your item list.